# MYSQL DATE_FORMAT to return additional day plus custom time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following which outputs `2015-05-06 10:30:00`

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' ' 10:30:00' )`

I would now like to increase the day so it outputs, `2015-05-07 10:30:00`

Using `DATE_ADD` I have been able to incease the date, however its now removed the time, `2015-05-07`

`SELECT (DATE(DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-(%m)-%d' ' 10:30:00'), INTERVAL +1 DAY)))`

How could i preserve the custom time? I would like the output to look like such:
`2015-05-07 10:30:00`. Thanks!

Comment: remove the date cast: just use `SELECT (DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-(%m)-%d' ' 10:30:00'), INTERVAL +1 DAY));`

Comment: perfect! Feel rather stupid, more you look at somethign like this the less you see! If you would like to answer ill happily accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much already there, removing the extra ( not required ) *Date* cast :

```
SELECT (DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-(%m)-%d' ' 10:30:00'), INTERVAL
+1 DAY));
```

which gives

**output**

> 2015-05-07 10:30:00

Answer (score 0):

You `concat()` instead of just putting the two strings next to each other:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d'), ' 10:30:00' )
```

And for tomorrow:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW( ), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d'), ' 10:30:00' )
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, would there be any benefit over the soloution mentioned by amdixon?

Comment: @atoms . . . I prefer using `concat()` explicitly, precisely to prevent the type of problem that you encountered.

Comment: @atoms . . . I should add, that the answer by amdixon returns a date rather than a string -- and a string appears to be the intention of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:-

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d' ' 10:30:00'),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS DATE;
```